# Why can't I declare a variable as a 2D array just once?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a table from which I want to select the first column with fieldnames and another column with the values. That second column is variable, depending on the input of the function.

I store the retrieved information in a 2D array.

This way it works:

```
  var person = 'jack'
  var parameters = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID__CONFIGURATION).getSheetByName('Parameters').getDataRange().getValues();
  var cVar = [];
  for (var p = 0; p < parameters.length; p++){
    cVar[p] = [];
    cVar[p][0] = parameters[p][0];
    cVar[p][1] = parameters[p][parameters[0].indexOf(person)];
  }
```

But it seems useless to me to have the line

```
    cVar[p] = [];
```

Why doesnt this work:

```
  var person = 'jack'
  var parameters = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID__CONFIGURATION).getSheetByName('Parameters').getDataRange().getValues();
  var cVar = [[]];
  for (var p = 0; p < parameters.length; p++){
    cVar[p][0] = parameters[p][0];
    cVar[p][1] = parameters[p][parameters[0].indexOf(person)];
  }
```

Comment: Take a careful  look at it in the debugger.  You can see how it grows inside of cVar.  It's similar to adding rows in a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way.

```
var cVar = []; // creates a new array
for(var p = 0; p < parameters.length; p++) {
  cVar[p] = []; // creates a new array for each p
  ...
}
```

In the other case:

```
var cVar = [[]];  // creates an array for p = 0;
// but cVar[1] is undefined so cVar[p][0] for p = 1 is undefined
// you need to explicitly create a new array for each p
for (var p = 0; p < parameters.length; p++){
  cVar[p][0] = parameters[p][0];
  cVar[p][1] = parameters[p][parameters[0].indexOf(person)];
}
```

Comment: Would have thought that gas/javascript would be itself more intelligent and create the array by itself when you would do anything like cVar[a][b][c][d] = value.

Comment: Actually javascript is pretty smart.  If you ever programed in c language you could reference cVar[a][b][c][d] and overwrite something else in that memory space and introduce a bug.  So javascript protects from writing outside the array by throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

You are only declaring the first element as a array with `cVar =[[]]`. What about the second element?

```
cVar =[
/**element 1**/ [],
]
```

Using `console.log(cVar[1])`, accessing the second element will return `undefined`.  You need to declare each element in `cVar` as a array, before putting elements inside.